# plot copy number gains and losses based on segmentation values using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with sampleID, chromosome, start and end positions of the chromosome and the mean segmenation value columns. The dataframe looks as follows

| ID | chrom | start.pos | end.pos | seg.mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | 1 | 93709 | 186180000 | -0.0638 |
| sample1 | 1 | 186270000 | 199590000 | 0.2779 |
| sample1 | 1 | 199860000 | 249210311 | -0.0298 |
| sampleN | 10 | 90000 | 135472374 | -0.0223 |

I would like to plot chromosomes 1-22 on the x axis their thickness defined by the size and separate the chromosome into chromosomal arms. further I would like to plot all the segmentation values on y axis, putting them as dots. It would also be great if I could color segmentation values which are above or below a certain cut-off to defined as a gain or loss. Something like the plot below but without calculating the frequency and having dots for all segmentation values instead of the lines.
[image: CNV gain or loss frequency]

Comment: Do you have [data and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) to share?

Comment: Hey John, no, but the above graphic is from copynumber package R.

Answer (score 0):

Take a glance at [`GenVisR` package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenVisR.html), it's based on `ggplot2`

For your question in particular: https://genviz.org/module-03-genvisr/0003/05/01/cnFreq_GenVisR/